# Entity framework generate edmx from postgresql

Tags: c#, entity-framework, postgresql, orm, edmx

I wont to use entity framework to generate edmx from postgresql.
I tried to use this [guide](http://rob.conery.io/2014/02/05/using-entity-framework-6-with-postgresql/) and it works fine, but I need to generate edmx and when I tried to create an edmx file, the Npgsql driver wasn't there.
[image]
Does anyone know a way to create a edmx file from postgresql with entity framework?
Or know about anther ORM for postgresql that can generate edmx like entity framework and you linq?
TNX

Comment: If you're using `npgsql` then make sure that `Install-Package Npgsql.EntityFramework` is installed.

Comment: I install it, but still can`t create edmx file. I can see in this video that it can be done. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ClLa1zP80Lc

Comment: Same question here. I know how to generate from MySQL or other database but something seems missing with Postgres.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same issue. I have solved it by installing the Npgsql PostgreSQL Integration extension for Visual Studio.

You can download it directly from Visual Studio Marketplace at this link: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=RojanskyS.NpgsqlPostgreSQLIntegration

After installing it, I can now see the provider for PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to install provider for Postgres:

https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/releases?after=v3.1.2

With this I have:

[Provider](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mhbem.jpg)